# Show only <tr>'s that have <td>'s with no content?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm trying to create a jQuery toggle button with this usage:

EDIT (I think this logic is more concise): Hide only `<tr class="todo-list">`'s that have `<td class="todo-assigned">`'s WITH content.

```
$('#empty_items').on("click", function(e) {
    $(".todo-list").filter(function(i) { return $(this).find("> .todo-assigned:empty") }).toggle();
});
```

^That's what I have but I know it's not correct.

```
<tr class="todo-list">
    <td class="todo-assigned">CONTENT!</td>
</tr>

<tr class="todo-list">
    <td class="todo-assigned"></td>
</tr>

<tr class="todo-list">
    <td class="todo-assigned">CONTENT!</td>
</tr>

<tr class="todo-list">
    <td class="todo-assigned"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Objects are truthy, so returning the jQuery object won't actually filter anything. Return its length instead, as empty jQuery objects have a length of `0`, which is falsy:

```
return $(this).children('.todo-assigned:empty').length
```

You can also do this entirely within the selector string with `:has`, but it'll be slower:

```
$('#todo-list tr:has(> .todo-assigned:empty)').toggle()
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pu2KA/**

Comment: Thank you for the answer Blender. After looking at your answer, I revised my original question to include this logic (I think it would be easier to define than the opposite): Hide <tr class="todo-list">'s that have <td class="todo-assigned">'s WITH content.

Comment: @eclipsis: `:empty` and `:parent` are opposites, so you won't really simplify much by inverting it.

Comment: What I was trying to clarify is the usage "Hide only <td>'s with content," instead of "Show only <td>'s with content." I didn't think I was specific on that. The button should toggle two states: (1, default) <td>'s both with and without content, and (2) only <td>'s without content.

Comment: @eclipsis: Are you hiding the `<td>`s or the `<tr>`s?

Comment: Hiding the <tr>'s that contain <td>'s WITH content.

Comment: @eclipsis: Right. You can't really simplify it any more.

Comment: Would your original answer still apply?

Comment: @eclipsis: I had only one, so yes.

Comment: @eclipsis: In that case, just replace `:empty` with `:parent`

Comment: Got it. Is there a reason replacing .addClass with toggle doesn't allow the toggle function?

Comment: @eclipsis: It's easier to show what the selector matches if I just highlight the elements, which is `.addClass` makes simple.

Comment: I'm not trying to highlight them, I want to toggle show/hide. Currently it only hides with the :parent selector, not toggling.

Comment: @eclipsis: Well, that's not something that should be happening if this is the only code that you have: http://jsfiddle.net/pu2KA/2/